# IIS redirect and url string replacement

Tags: iis, redirect

Is there a way to write a redirect rule so that any occurrence, of say "newyork", anywhere in the URL can be redirected to the same url with "new-york" as the string's replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with this IIS Extension:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

It's quite the same as mod_rewrite in Apache.

Comment: i have hard-coded rewrite rules that i put in my web.config file without the use of the tool. i guess i can give it a shot to see how to replace occurrences of a string.